# Lazy Loading in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am pre-loading the below HTML on page load

```
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
<div>Content for lazy load </div>
```

Now I am now loading content each time I scroll down the page where a DIV tag is visible, this works fine. Here is an example of the code I am running:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
ajax funxtion(passing argumran div1) 
});
```

The problem is when I get to the bottom of page I have to scroll up again to get content.

Is there is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't load content for every scroll event. check the scrolltop value of document each time you scroll. and if it is below some specific point load your content.

and here is some code example with some extra controls for "not load while scrolling up" etc.

```
 var lastScrollTop = 0;

 $(window).scroll(function () {

     var st = $(this).scrollTop();

      //load content if the user below %75 of the page
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() * 0.75) {
           if (st > lastScrollTop) {
               //Get ContentGet
           }

            lastScrollTop = st;
      }                
 });
```